# Statistical distributions

Tags: r, probability, distributions, normal-distribution, beta-distribution

I got an assignment in which I had to gather data and then fit a statistical distribution (e.g. gaussian, beta, gamma, lognormal and exponential) to this data in R in the form of a probability function and an cumulative distribution function. Is this a normal procedure when you gather data? And can you always fit your data to a statistical distribution?

Comment: I don't consider this a normal procedure and it often is not a sensible procedure. It's best to derive a distribution model based on theoretical considerations of domain knowledge.That might not lead to one distribution model but to several and one could then use data to decide between them. However, just trying the distributions you mention doesn't make sense. They don't even have the same [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)).

Comment: What do you mean by support?

Comment: WIth a cullen and frey graph I can find out which distribution models might be useful?

Comment: Follow the link, it explains what the support of a function is. What I mean is that the beta distribution is defined between 0 and 1 whereas the normal distribution is defined between -Inf and +Inf. Your decision for one of them shouldn't just be informed by a graph. Anyway, your first step should be to consider why you need to fit a distribution model. Very often you don't need to do that at all.